# Put image next to div in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have new in Bootsrap, and I am having a problem putting an image next to another div, it is always displayed below it. I tried resizing the image and some other things but it didn't work.
Here is the code:

```
       <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-lg"><h1>Services</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 hidden-lg">
                   <img src="img/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="logo" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to put your row content into a div class="container"

Then, if you want to show your image next to the text, you can add the class col-xs-4 (or other numbers) to your columns.

Your final code will be something like:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4 hidden-lg"><h1>Services</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4 hidden-lg">
                   <img src="img/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="logo" />
                </div>
  </div>
</div>
```